# Type issue with Scala when dealing with timestamps

Tags: scala, scalatra

Straight forward problem that I don't see what I'm doing wrong in - some type mismatch somewhere. Basically trying to set a default datatype of Long on parameters that are coming in from a web request. Here's the code:

```
val startTs:Long = params.getOrElse("start_ts", DateTime.yesterdayAsEpoch).toLong
val endTs:Long = params.getOrElse("end_ts", DateTime.todayAsEpoch).toLong
```

My DateTime helper code:

```
def todayAsEpoch: Long = {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))
    c.setTime(new java.util.Date())
    c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0,0)
    c.getTimeInMillis / 1000L
  }

  def yesterdayAsEpoch: Long = {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))
    c.setTime(new java.util.Date())
    c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),0,0,0)
    ((c.getTimeInMillis / 1000L) - 86400)
  }
```

And finally, the error:

```
value toLong is not a member of Any
[error]         val startTs:Long = params.getOrElse("start_ts", DateTime.yesterdayAsEpoch).toLong
[error]                                                                                    ^
[error] /vagrant/src/main/scala/com/myapp/api/controllers/FooController.scala:437: value toLong is not a member of Any
[error]         val endTs:Long = params.getOrElse("end_ts", DateTime.todayAsEpoch).toLong
[error]                                                                            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say what `params` is. It looks like it might be a `Map[String, X]` with some type `X`. `params.getOrElse(key, someLong)` will considered to have  the best common supertype of `X` and `Long` which happens to be `Any`, according to the error message, and which has no toLong method. As your default value happens to be Long already, and so don't need to be converted, I guess there is a `toLong` method on `X`.

If it is so, then you should convert the value retrieved from `params` to `Long` (when there is such a value), before providing the default value. That would be :

```
params.get("key").map(_.toLong).getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `params` is a `Map[String, Something]`, and that `Something` isn't always a numeric type. (String?) In any case, when you call `params.getOrElse`, it's inferring a common type between `Something` and `Long`, and finding `Any`, which is why you can't call `toLong` on it.